# json_encode get data in single quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I have array like

```
$array = ['key1' => 'Value1','key2' => 'Value2',];
```

on `json_encode($array)` giving output

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},
```

But i want output like

```
{'key1':'values1', 'key2':'value2'}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Values in single quotes are considered __invalid json__. Explain, why you need this?

Comment: See [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and [json.org](http://www.json.org/) on how to properly format JSON

Comment: Try to surround your input values with double quotes: $array = ["'key1'" => "'Value1'","'key2'" => "'Value2'",];